# How to efficiently get a string of values stored in a dataframe from a string of ids?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm working with two dataframes:

```
1. name_basics:

 nconst      primaryName
0  nm0000001     Fred Astaire
1  nm0000002    Lauren Bacall
2  nm0000003  Brigitte Bardot
3  nm0000004     John Belushi
4  nm0000005   Ingmar Bergman

2. title_directors:

 tconst            directors
0  tt0000574            nm0846879
1  tt0000591            nm0141150
2  tt0000679  nm0091767,nm0877783
3  tt0001184  nm0063413,nm0550220
4  tt0001258            nm0088881
```

What i'm looking for is something like this:

```
tconst            directors
0  tt0000574      name1
1  tt0000591      name2
2  tt0000679      name3,name4
3  tt0001184      name5,name6
4  tt0001258      name7
```

I tried to do so by defining a function getNames and then doing

```
title_directors['directors'] = title_directors['directors'].apply(getNames)
```

```
def getNames(nconsts):
    nconstList = nconsts.split(',')
    retString = ''
    for nconst in nconstList:
        df = name_basics[name_basics['nconst'] == nconst]['primaryName']
        if not df.empty:
            retString += df.iloc[0] + ', '
    return retString[:-2]

getNames('nm0063413,nm0550220')
'Ricardo de Baños, Alberto Marro'
```

But this is way too slow (it would take like 80hrs on my computer). I was wondering what is the correct way to do this.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you had those one by one, the `pandas` `join` tool can do exactly this.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html  You could certainly speed things up by making `nconst` the key for `name_basics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
import pprint

import pandas as pd

name_basics = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
title_directors = pd.read_csv("filer.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

print(name_basics)
print(title_directors)

# split by comma
title_directors["directors"] = title_directors["directors"].str.split(",")

# explode the DataFrame
td = title_directors.explode("directors")

# map the name_basics DataFrame onto the directors column
td["directors"] = td["directors"].map(name_basics.set_index("nconst").squeeze()).fillna("")

# un-explode
res = td.groupby("tconst").agg(",".join).reset_index()

# remove unwanted commnas from the new column
res["directors"] = res["directors"].str.strip(",")
print(res)
```

For a `name_basics` DataFrame as follows:

```
      nconst      primaryName
0  nm0000001     Fred Astaire
1  nm0000002    Lauren Bacall
2  nm0000003  Brigitte Bardot
3  nm0000004     John Belushi
4  nm0000005   Ingmar Bergman
```

and a `title_directors` as follows:

```
      tconst            directors
0  tt0000574            nm0000001
1  tt0000591            nm0141150
2  tt0000679  nm0091767,nm0000004
3  tt0001184  nm0063413,nm0550220
4  tt0001258            nm0088881
```

it gives the following output:

```
      tconst     directors
0  tt0000574  Fred Astaire
1  tt0000591              
2  tt0000679  John Belushi
3  tt0001184              
4  tt0001258
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful :).
I had to add ['PrimaryName'] after .squeeze() but everything else worked great!

Comment: @alanacevedo Glad I could help!